# Is there a way to find out a list of Actions that have been optimized for Smart Screen devices?

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google, smartscreen

I would like to learn from the look of other Actions that are running on Smart Screen devices. So I want to find Actions that have been optimized to work with Smart Screen devices.

Is there a way to search https://assistant.google.com/explore somehow for these type of Actions?

Comment: On this site https://developers.google.com/actions/surfaces/displays

At the bottom of the page, there are some Actions that seem to be related to Smart Displays, I hope this helps somewhat. I am unclear on what exactly you need, sorry.

Comment: @Jacob this is exactly what I need, but that list has only 3 Actions. It would be great to have a [much] bigger list.

Comment: I am sorry :( that is all I could find. I will add it as an answer and see if I can find more later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On this [Google Documentation Site](https://developers.google.com/actions/surfaces/displays) At the bottom of the page, there are some Actions that seem to be related to Smart Displays. I will continue to look for some more examples.